# Can I define a jsp custom tag to extend a standard html tag?

Tags: jsp, custom-attributes, custom-tag

For example:

```
<c:a href="/myurl" style="margin: 5px;" addJsessionId="true" logEvent="true">
  click here</c:a>
```

such that:

1) all standard attributes of  (style) are propagated as is.

2) my tag handler implementation handles the custom attributes (addJsessionId and logEvent in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy enough. JSP allows you define a tag with [dynamic attributes](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaln.html#bnalr), which essentially means the attributes are passed to the custom tag object as generic name/value pair rather than via setters as with normal tag attributes. This means you can transparently support arbitrary HTML attributes without declaring them individually in your tag class.

So, [write a subclass of `SimpleTagSupport`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html), with your [custom attributes fully defined and implemented](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html#bnans), and then [enable dynamic attributes for that tag](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html#bnanu).

It's still up to you to generate the actual HTML from the tag code, but that should be straightforward.